# Rotation Matrix

Tags: game-engine, mathematics, matrix

i am having a hard time trying to dechiper how blender game engine allocate the rotation values on the rotation Matrix, this website describes the values like this.[image: Rotation Matrix Value]

But when i print the rotation matrix on the console it give me weird positions[image: Console Matrix]

That value 0.766 should be on the first column first row where the 1.0 value is, that value should describe the rotation on x. Plz halp :c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rotated the object around the X-axis. In other words it is a rotation on the YZ-plane.

The projection on the X-axis (rotation axis) will remain unchanged, regardless how much you turn the object. It was (0,0,0) and is still (0,0,0).

Hint: the rotation axis does not change.

The rotation is a 2D-rotation on the YZ-plane. Here you can see the formulas you might remember from school:

$$x = \sin(\alpha)$$
$$y = \cos(\alpha)$$

As we have a plane, we can use a [2D rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha)\\
\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

One component is y the other is z.

Comment: Sorry, i figured out this like a week ago, yes that was my bad xD, i need to rotate around z axis. Thx a lot :)